# Calculating a marimekko/stacked chart in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, math, svg

I have input data which has varying number of data items, and a matching number of value items. I know there are libraries out there already, but I'm on a journey to create my own one ;)

So if there are 3 columns, there are 3 values per column (as a marimekko chart is):

[image: Marimekko chart example]

I have the following data dummy inputs, but they can range from any positive value:

```js
const json = `{ "data": [ 
  { "value": [ 1,  2,  3,  4] }, 
  { "value": [ 5,  6,  7,  8] },
  { "value": [ 9, 10, 11, 12] },
  { "value": [13, 14, 15, 16] } 
] }`
```

With it, I have got the following to calculate the total of each column (so, `[ 1, 5, 9, 13 ], [ 2, 6, 10, 14 ] ... etc`:

```js
const stackIndexTotal = (
  dataJSON.slice(1).reduce( ( (sums, { value } ) =>
    sums.map( ( sum, i ) => sum + value[ i ] )
  ), dataJSON[0].value )
);
```

At the moment I have this code and output:

```js
// dummy data
const json = `{ "data": [ 
  { "value": [ 1,  2,  3,  4] }, 
  { "value": [ 5,  6,  7,  8] },
  { "value": [ 9, 10, 11, 12] },
  { "value": [13, 14, 15, 16] } 
] }`,
  dataJSON = JSON.parse(json).data;

// find the sum of all the values at same index
const stackIndexTotal = (
  dataJSON.slice(1).reduce(((sums, {
      value
    }) =>
    sums.map((sum, i) => sum + value[i])
  ), dataJSON[0].value)
);


// loop the data
dataJSON.forEach((data, index) => {

  // variables
  const dataContainer = document.getElementById('data-container');
  const dataItem = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');

  // inside the data:{}
  const numberOfValues = dataJSON.length;

  // loop the value array
  data.value.forEach((item, i) => {

    // inside the value:[]
    const numberOfValueInArray = data.value.length;

    const rectHeight = (item / stackIndexTotal[index]) * 100;

    // 100 width view, divided by number of groups
    const widthOfSections = (100 / numberOfValues);

    // add in text items
    dataItem.innerHTML += (

      // the rectangle svg
      // -- fill: dummy colours - each index, or same column has same colour
      // -- x: offset of the xPosition
      // -- width: fixed width for demo
      // -- height: height of rect is percentage of arrays column total
      // -- y: need to calculate offset

      `<rect
        fill="hsl(20, 30%, ${ ((100 / numberOfValues) * index) }%)"
        x="${ (widthOfSections * i ) }"
        width="${ widthOfSections }"
        height="${ rectHeight }"

        y="0"
       ></rect>`
    );

  });

  // add into the DOM
  dataContainer.appendChild(dataItem);

});
```

```css
svg {
  max-width: 25em;
  max-height: 25em;
  border: 2px solid;
  margin: 2em 5em;
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"><g id="data-container"></g></svg>
```

But was hoping to get the following output.

[image: intended output]

This way once I can get the offset correct, I can make all the values a percentage of the `Math.max(...stackIndexTotal)`.

At the moment, any thing I try in the two loops seems to not offset the blocks correctly. I've tried getting the previous value: `data.value[ i - 1 ]` and then using that percentage to make it the starting point, but that seems to not work. I've tried working with the first loop `index` to make all the `index === 0 ? 0` so they all start at the top, but then the offsets for each item afterwards seems off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the future person wanting to create one of these graphs - and going through the same struggle. @enxaneta had a great solution but it didn't scale beyond the fixed values.

For my solution:

```js
// dummy data
const json = `{ "data": [ 
  { "value": [ 1,  2,  3,  4] }, 
  { "value": [ 5,  6,  7,  8] },
  { "value": [ 9, 10, 11, 12] },
  { "value": [13, 14, 15, 16] } 
] }`,
  dataJSON = JSON.parse(json).data;

// rework the data
// -- get the columns
// -- then the sum of the columns
const dataJSONColumn = dataJSON.map((current, index, arr) => {
    // create the blanks
    let outputArray = [],
      previousTotal = 0;

    // loop through
    for (let i = 0; i < current.value.length; i++) {
      // if it is first item
      if (i < 1) {
        // set the value to 0
        previousTotal = 0;
      } else {
        // add from the last value
        previousTotal += arr[i - 1].value[index];
      }

      // output the new array
      outputArray.push(previousTotal);
    }

    return outputArray;
  }),
  // get the sum of all vertical values
  stackIndexTotal = dataJSON
  .slice(1)
  .reduce(
    (sums, {
      value
    }) => sums.map((sum, i) => sum + value[i]),
    dataJSON[0].value
  ),
  // number of dataItems
  numberOfDataItems = dataJSON.length;

// begin the loop
dataJSON.forEach((data, index) => {
  // variables
  const dataContainer = document.getElementById("data-container");

  // cache wrapper
  const dataValue = Array.isArray(data.value) ? data.value : [data.value],
    // number of [value] points
    numberInValueArray = dataValue.length,
    // -- size of the group sections
    widthOfColumn = 100 / numberOfDataItems,
    // sum of new array
    dataJSONColumnTotal = dataJSONColumn[index][dataJSONColumn[index].length - 1],
    // create the data-item
    dataItem = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");

  // loop the values
  dataValue.forEach((item, i) => {
    // how tall is the bar in the stack
    const stackDataItemPercent = (item / stackIndexTotal[i]) * 100,
      // how far to offset it
      stackDataItemOffset = (dataJSONColumn[i][index] / stackIndexTotal[i]) * 100;

    // bar item value
    dataItem.innerHTML += `
                                    <rect
                                        width="${widthOfColumn}"
                                        height="${stackDataItemPercent}"
                                        fill="hsl(120, 30%, ${ ((100 / numberInValueArray) * index) }%)"
                                        x="${widthOfColumn * i}"
                                        y="${stackDataItemOffset}"
                                    />
                                `;
  });

  // add into the DOM
  dataContainer.appendChild(dataItem);
});
```

```css
svg {
  max-width: 25em;
  margin: 2em 5em;
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"><g id="data-container"></g></svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you ask.

Using the data I'm calculating the position x,y and size (width and height) of the rects to draw. Please read comments in the code.

```js
const SVG_NS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
let container = document.querySelector("#data-container");

const json_ry = {
  data: [
    { value: [1, 2, 3, 4] },
    { value: [5, 6, 7, 8] },
    { value: [9, 10, 11, 12] },
    { value: [13, 14, 15, 16] },
    { value: [17, 18, 19, 20] }
  ]
};

let lngth = json_ry.data.length;


// creating an array with the heights of the rectangles
let heights = new Array(lngth);
heights.fill([]);

for (let i = 0; i < heights.length; i++) {
  heights[i] = json_ry.data[i].value
}


// create an array with the y positions of the rects 
let positions = [];
//by copying the heights array  

for (let i = 0; i < heights.length; i++) {
  positions[i] = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < heights[i].length; j++) {
    positions[i][j] = heights[i][j];
  }
}
//then calculate the y position as a sum of the previous position and the previous height
positions[0] = [0, 0, 0, 0];
for (let i = 1; i < positions.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < positions[i].length; j++) {
    positions[i][j] = positions[i - 1][j] + heights[i - 1][j];
  }
}

//console.log("heights",heights)
//console.log("positions",positions)

for (let i = 0; i < heights.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < heights[i].length; j++) {
  //build an object with attributes for the rect
    let o = {
      x: j * 25,
      y: positions[i][j],
      width: 25,
      height: heights[i][j],
      fill: `hsl(0,30%,${(i / lngth) * 100}%)`
    };
    //create a new rectangle
    drawSVGelmt(o, "rect", container);
  }
}


// a function to create and draw an svg element
function drawSVGelmt(o, tag, parent) {
  let elmt = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, tag);
  for (let name in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      elmt.setAttributeNS(null, name, o[name]);
    }
  }
  parent.appendChild(elmt);
  return elmt;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100"><g id="data-container"></g></svg>
```

Comment: thank you! you're on the right track 100%, but it doesn't seem to scale? and every array is to match in the value array